# Most readable way to format long if conditions?

Tags: coding-style, conditions

Long winding `if` conditions should be avoided if at all possible, yet sometimes we all end up writing them. Even if it's a very simple condition, the involved statements are sometimes simply very wordy, so the whole condition ends up being very lengthy. What's the most readable way to format those?

```
if (FoobarBaz::quxQuux(corge, grault) || !garply(waldo) || fred(plugh) !== xyzzy) {
    thud();
}
```

or

```
if (
    FoobarBaz::quxQuux(corge, grault)
 || !garply(waldo)
 || fred(plugh) !== xyzzy
) {
    thud();
}
```

or

```
if (FoobarBaz::quxQuux(corge, grault)
    || !garply(waldo)
    || fred(plugh) !== xyzzy) {
    thud();
}
```

or

```
thudable = FoobarBaz::quxQuux(corge, grault);
thudable ||= !garply(waldo);
thudable ||= fred(plugh) !== xyzzy;

if (thudable) {
    thud();
}
```

or any other preferences?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Often, a long if condition is the sign of code that needs refactoring, but sometimes you can't avoid it. In those cases, I prefer the first:

```
if (bar || baz || quux) { ... }
```

Because you're able to tell what's going on with one line. However, I'd much rather do something like this, when possible:

```
function foo() {
  return bar || baz || quux;
}

if (foo()) { ... }
```

Comment: scrolling to the side vs vertical is not nearly the limitation it was in the bad old days...

Comment: and give a meaningfull (business) name to the function so that people understand what's tested here.

Comment: Wow! this solution is so clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

I like keeping the operators at the end to indicate continuation:

```
if (the_function_being_called() != RETURNCODE_SUCCESS &&
    the_possibly_useful_recovery_strategy() == RETURNCODE_EPICFAIL &&
    this_user_has_elected_to_recieve_error_reports)
{
    report_error();
}
```

Comment: I think I like this one. I employ a lot of parenthesis to ensure I can understand the order of precedence too.

Comment: I prefer putting the logical operators on the start of the line so as I read a line I can easily see it is part of the conditional and not just a regular line of code.

Comment: gofmt moves the { up, which results in less readable code

Answer (score 13):

I am a big fan of meaningful variable names:

```
const bool isInAStrangeCondition =
    FoobarBaz::quxQuux(corge, grault) ||
    !garply(waldo) ||
    fred(plugh) !== xyzzy;

if (isInAStrangeCondition) {
    thud();
}
```

Or refactor as a function, as mentioned above.

Comment: +1 This answer is analogous to the accepted one, but uses a local variable, which might be preferred in many cases over a new function.

Answer (score 10):

I tend to align the operators at the start of new lines so I remember how I'm combining terms (both for long logic and long arithmetic).  Like this:

```
if (first_attempt(data) == SUCCESS
    || (reusable(data) && second_attempt(data) == SUCCESS)
    || (still_reusable(data) && third_attempt(data) == SUCCESS))
  return SUCCESS;
```

This only works if I indent by 2-spaces or set set my environment to indent multiline predicates more, or else it would be hard to tell where the predicate ends and useful code begins.

Answer (score 10):

I break out the messier subexpressions, or all of them, as bool variables.  Then the top-level boolean logic of the 'if' statement can be made clear.  In the kind of work I do, it's not always several things ORed or ANDed.

```
bool goodblah = some_mess < whatever;
bool frobnacious = messy_crud != junky_expression;
bool yetanother = long_winded_condition;

if (goodblah || (frobnacious && yetanother))   {
    ...
}
```

This is especially good in a debugger, where I can look at all the bools before executing the 'if'.

Comment: I like this as well, but you do lose one benefit: it is no longer possible to short-circuit expensive comparisons anymore.

Comment: ... And you need to be very good at naming tons of variables all days...

Comment: You could also write the comparisons as lazy evaluating expressions and you wouldn't lose the short-circuit advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the following:

```
if (really_long_expression && another_really_really_long_expression && 
            another_very_long_expression_OMG_id_it_long){
    bugs();
}
```

This way it still looks like an if expression and not a broken-down-to-pieces if expression. The indentation helps in showing that it is a continuation of the previous line.

You can also indent it until the opening bracket is at the end of the previous line so that it's at the end of the if expression as it's supposed to be.

Comment: I really liked your bugs() method :D